# Basic google app engine (python) templating issue

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

after going through some basic tutorials on the app engine and the webapp framework, I'm attempting to display documents that are related to a project construct I've created (e.g {% ifequal project.key doc.parentproject %} ) I have created several documents that do indeed have a doc.parentproject identical to keys from the project, but somehow this for loop never runs. If I substitute project.key for an actual project key value, then it returns true for those specific kets. Is there some basic templating thing I'm missing here? I haven't been able to find any answers on google or the django site (webapp uses the django templating engine). Any help would be appreciated.

Sorry if this is basic newb material...

```
{% for project in projects %}
  <blockquote>  
<div style="border:1px solid #999; padding:20px;">  
<h3>{{ project.projectname|escape }} </h3>

<h5>{{ project.key }}</h5>

    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="600">
        <tr>
            <td>Doc Feed Name</td>
            <td>Feed author</td>
            <td>Spreadsheet URL</td>
            <td>Parent Project Key</td>
            <td>Created on</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

    {% for doc in docs %}
        {% ifequal project.key doc.parentproject %}
            <tr>
                <td>doc name:{{ doc.name|escape }}</td>
                <td>{{ doc.author }}</td>
                <td>{{ doc.link }}</td>
                <td>{{ doc.parentproject }}</td>
                <td>{{ doc.date }}</td>
                <td>Delete</td>
            </tr>
        {% endifequal %}
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

{% endfor %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the controller code that provides the values to this template, it is difficult to really diagnose the problem that you are having, but I would guess that the *docs* variable  isn't getting the list of *doc* entities that it clearly expects.

From a good design standpoint, I would suggest giving the Project entity a property that contains a list of the docs that are associated with it. It looks like each doc is dependent on a parent project, so it would be cleaner and easier to have this code:

```
 {% for doc in project.docs %}
   ...do my rendering here...
 {% endfor %}
```

than what you have.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great suggestion. I'm a newb here, so thinking about this differently helps a lot.

Comment: @travist: welcome to SO. It is customary to vote-up helpful / useful answers.  You are also encouraged to accept the most helpful answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: travist, you are quite welcome. Don't worry about feeling like a newb. Your question was actually well-written and included a useful code sample. That alone puts you in the top 5% of SO newbs.

Answer (score 0):

If a "doc" is an entity, and "parentproject" is a ReferenceProperty on that entity, the problem here is that you're attempting to compare a Key with an entity (ReferenceProperties automatically resolve their references). You need to use this instead:

```
{% ifequal project.key doc.parentproject.key %}
```